# How to find the longest side of a Javascript Element

Tags: javascript, height, width, element

I am trying to resize an element.  This is pretty straight forward.

I have a div, and a child div.

```
<div id="parent"><div id="child"></div></div>
```

These are created dynamically using JavaScript.

I am trying to define the longest side for the parent, so that I can resize an image that is within the child div.  The image might be longest along the side of its height, or width.

These divs change size dependant upon the output, and the image could be landscape or portrait, this is a user upload.

Is there a fast way to check the parent div for its longest side (height, width) as I don't know these as they are not static.

Comment: why did that not output my html

Comment: To show blocks of code in your questions you need to have an empty line before, and after, the code block and indent each line of code by four spaces. Or, to have code in-line, wrap the code in back-ticks (`\`code\``).

Comment: cheers ill keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery

```
Function checkSize(){
    var side;
    if ($('#parent').height() > $('#parent').width()) {
        side = "Height";
    }else if($('#parent').height() < $('#parent').width()) {
        side = "Width";
    }else($('#parent').height() == $('#parent').width()) {
        side = "Equal";
    }
    alert(side);
}
```

Comment: if(imageparent.clientHeight >= imageparent.clientWidth){
   maxsize = imageparent.clientHeight;
  }
  else if(imageparent.clientWidth >= imageparent.clientHeight){
   maxsize = imageparent.clientWidth;   
  }

Comment: yes thankyou, i am using pure javascript, it was the clientWidth and clientHeight that was the key i was looking for.  width and height were producing 0.

Comment: Now i just need to figure out how to append to a form the input fields for the images.  I have a form in PHP pulled to the page by AJAX, this is already working for over a dozen fields.  I dynamically create the input using javascript and can see it in the html in the browser debugger.

When i submit the form, they are not a part of the form.  I gather the form loaded via AJAX is not part of the DOM, and when i dynamically add field, they are not being adding to the Form DOM.

How does one pull the form from AJAX into the DOM to be able to append new fields to it.